# Line counts in Python

Tags: python

I have an input file contains data as:

```
0.0  0.000  0.0000  0.000   0.000
0.1  0.000  0.0000  0.000   0.000
0.2  0.000  0.0000  0.000   0.000
0.3  0.000  0.0000  0.000   0.000
0.4  1.7637  232323  23232  234242
0.65  21344   2134214  412412 214124
0.55  23423   32423    32423  32423
```

I need to add contents after last row which contains zeros only.which means a row after 0.3 is to be added.
I need my output as

```
  0.0  0.000  0.0000  0.000   0.000
  0.1  0.000  0.0000  0.000   0.000
  0.2  0.000  0.0000  0.000   0.000
  0.3  0.000  0.0000  0.000   0.000
  0.4  0.000  0.0000  0.000   0.000
  0.5  1.7637  232323  23232  234242
  0.75  21344   2134214  412412 214124
  0.65  23423   32423    32423  32423
```

Please help me with a code to reach my required output.
What I have tried is:

```
for line in f1:
  string=line
  if rthcount<=6:
     strplit=string.split()
     rign=strplit[1]
     if rign==0.0:
         print(string)
   else:
       f4.write(string)
   rthcount+=1
```

Please help me with a code to work this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete_this = ''
for line in f1:
    if all(float(part) == 0.0 for part in line.split()[1:]):
        f4.write(delete_this) 
        delete_this = line    # new candidate to remove
    else:
        f4.write(line)
        delete_this = '' # removed
```

EDIT: New requirements!!

```
add_this = None
for line in f1:
    if all(float(part) == 0.0 for part in line.split()[1:]):
        add_this = '0.000  0.000  0.000   0.000\n'
    elif add_this:
        f4.write(line.split()[0] + ' ' + add_this)
        add_this = None
    f4.write(line)
```

EDIT: MORE REQUIREMENTS

```
import itertools
add_this = None
line_number = ('0.{} '.format(n) for n in itertools.count())
for line in f1:
    line = line.split(None, 1)[1]
    if all(float(part) == 0.0 for part in line.split()):
        add_this = '0.000  0.000  0.000   0.000\n'
    elif add_this:
        f4.write(next(line_number) + add_this)
        add_this = None
    f4.write(next(line_number) + line)
```

EDIT: New requeriments again

```
add_this = None
value_to_add = 0

for line in f1:
    prefix, line = line.split(None, 1)
    if all(float(part) == 0.0 for part in line.split()):
        add_this = '{} 0.000  0.000  0.000   0.000\n'.format(
            float(prefix) + value_to_add + 0.1)
    elif add_this:
        f4.write(add_this)
        add_this = None
        value_to_add += 0.1
    f4.write('{} {}'.format(float(prefix) + value_to_add, line)
```

Comment: I have updated my requirement. Please give me a code to add rows after a row which contains 0.0.

Comment: ,I need to increment the line count also. Line count is not incrementing.I have updated my code. Please help

Comment: Please help to fix this.

Comment: @bin123 fixed !!

Comment: i need to increment the first column by 0.1 not by 1.

Comment: .I have updated my requirement.Please help to fix this. I need to increment first column by 0.1 .